# Eventhandlers in a separate document

Tags: javascript

I'd like to keep all my JavaScripts in a separate document and I like it that way. Now I've had problems with the last bit of code to move from my HTML-code into my separate JavaScript document.

I got two eventhandlers that looked like this:

```
<a href="http://www.commercial.se" onclick="confirmLeave()" target="_blank">
```

and

```
<IMG SRC="folder/pic_small.jpg" alt="Description"  onClick="view(this);">
```

This is the javascript code for the two eventhandlers:

```
function confirmLeave()
{
  if(confirm("Vill du lämna Blomstermåla-Bladet?")) {
    return true;
  } else {
    if(window.event) {
      window.event.returnValue = false;
    } else {
      e.preventDefault();
    }
    return false;
  }
}
```

And

```
function view(img) {
   imgsrc = img.src.split("_")[0] + "_big.jpg";
   viewwin = window.open(imgsrc,'viewwin', "width=790,height=444,location=0");  
  viewwin.focus();  
}
```

I've managed to solve my problem of not having the javascript code in my HTML document for the first onClick eventhandler by changing my HTML to this:

```
<a href="http://www.commercial.com" id="external-link" target="_blank">
```

And adding this to my javascript document:

```
function init()
{
    var link = document.getElementById("external-link");

    link.onclick = confirmLeave;
}

window.onload = init;
```

I've tried adding a similar solution to the other eventhandler but I can't figure out the code I need to use for it to work. I would like to know how to add that event handler into the init function as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 <a href="http://www.commercial.com" class="external-link" target="_blank"> 
 <IMG SRC="folder/pic_small.jpg" alt="Description" id = "external-image">

    function init() {
    var link = document.getElementById("external-link");

    var links = document.getElementsByClassName("external-link");
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].onclick = confirmLeave;
    }

    var image = document.getElementById("external-image");
    image.onclick = view;
}

window.onload = init;​
```

Instead of **img** in your function just use **this**

```
function view() {
   imgsrc = this.src.split("_")[0] + "_big.jpg";
   viewwin = window.open(imgsrc,'viewwin', "width=790,height=444,location=0");  
  viewwin.focus();  
}
```

Comment: @Benji .. Glad to have helped :)

Comment: Just another quick problem I ran into now... I need the first function to work on several links and for some reason it doesn't when I give it a class name and change to document.getElementByClassName("external-link"); How do I solve this?

Comment: Thank you Sushanth :) Solved it perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to change the `view` function, you can do something similar, with the slight difference that you need to pass the image as an argument to the `view` function.  You can do this by setting an anonymous function as the click handler.

```
<IMG SRC="folder/pic_small.jpg" alt="Description" id="some-img">
```

```
function init()
{
    var img = document.getElementById("some-img");

    img.onclick = function(){
        view(this);
    };
}
```

Comment: That did the trick perfectly to not change the view, thank you! :)